# Calculate impedance in time and frequency?

Tags: frequency, impedance, signal-processing

I'm characterizing the impedance of a system. To get the impedance I apply a sum of sinusoidal voltage waves that basically looks like noise.
[image]

I recorded the output current from the system. As you can see there seems to be some time dependence on the output.  I was wondering how to get the time and frequency dependence of the impedance.
[image]

Comment: It’s pretty hard to measure impedance changes of a biological cell due to laser emission on brainwaves at such low frequencies and low capacitance, but if you inject a lower power  than the absorbed optical  power at much higher frequency then you can get a ceramic band pass filter to improve the impedance amplitude and phase measurement with a signal noise ratio much better than 20dB instead of 0 dB As shown. With impedance matching to 1k converted to whatever this might be called the z11 transform. Or the impedance measurement of return loss s11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough time resolution to tell.

But it looks inductive, with noisy current sense and insufficient samples shown,

Try reducing noise with a filter and try an XY scope with the same bandwidth to get the dominant phase. Try DSO FFT.

Current starts with an envelope and reduces with high-frequency noise.

It's better to characterize with a Bode Analyzer or swept amplitude phase response with an output relative to input.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, will this work if the impedance is changing in time?

Comment: It depends on the frequency, impedance and time domain. Can you show your design specs , photo , measurements and the problem. ?. 
All I can say is it looks like 1k impedance with attenuation as frequency of noise increases.

Comment: Looking at your previous question on laser induce capacitance changes in a membrane I would consider a touch sensor circuit or a high impedance oscillator that changes frequency with external capacitance tuned by laser injection.  Photo diodes conduct more and increase capacitance when the bias current  increases. cells may have similar behaviors. But probe inductance and cell pF must be given. (0.5 to 1nH/mm)

Comment: In the end I just used different sine waves and applied the Hilbert transform to get the impedance at each frequency

Comment: Can you pls. explain in answer how that works?

Comment: Instead of using several sinusoidal waves I just used one, then you can get the instantaneous amplitude and phase of the signal using the Hilbert transform. Then repeat for different frequencies and you can get the time dependent impedance at different frequencies.

Comment: OK  I have never used the Hilbert transform before and I don't know how that measures amplitude and phase. I've used Optical spectrum analyzers so perhaps that's what they use.